# Firebug shows 404 error for claro_rtl.css, but I can't find the source that is trying to reference that file

Tags: css, dojo, http-status-code-404, firebug

I'm in the middle of testing a customized Dojo theme based on the popular claro theme.  The new theme is named 'jelam'.   I've gone through all the suggested steps for making a new theme based on an existing theme like claro and all seems to be working fine - except Firebug is reporting an error immediately upon opening my page.  It reports that it can't find the claro_rtl.css file.  The thing is, I've searched many times my source code and files for any reference to that claro_rtl.css file, but I can't find it.  I suspected initially that my browser was cacheing it somehow, so I cleared the Firefox browser, closed Firefox and ropened it, and also restarted the WebSphere portal which is serving my JSP page.  Despite those attempts to clear out any reference to claro_rtl.css, I'm still getting the error reported in Firebug.

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://localhost:10149/CompassThemesURS/themes/html/commonurs/dojo/1.9.1/dijit/themes/jelam/claro_rtl.css"
```

How can I get Firebug to show me what the source of that request is?  I had initially suspected that I had missed it in one of my many JSP files or CSS files that was possibly importing it, but it's not showing up.

Is there a way to get Firebug to show me who is trying to pull that file in?

Thanks for any insight you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.  In Firebug I put "claro_rtl.css" in the search box, then performed the search in each tab until the search found it from the CSS tab, and it found it referenced in the new jelam.css file.

I had forgotten to redeploy the webapp.  I had correctly updated the source files, including jelam.css, but I hadn't redeployed with those updates like I thought I had.

Cheers.